# Using external TypeScript script in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have a TypeScript file, test.ts, with the following content:

```
private method(){

 //some operations
}
```

How i use the "method" method inside a Javascript file?

Comment: It's private. It's not meant to be called from the outside. Your question needs more details as to why you want to do such thing instead of exposing the method as public

Answer (score 0):

Typescript files will be compiled into javascript files before running. You can expose your typescript function in **global scope** like the following code. And javascript can call it.

typescript

```js
window.globalFunc = () => {
  console.log("globalFunc called")
}
```

In javascript, you can access it through the global window

```js
window.globalFunc()
```

Even thought it is feasible. But it is really **not recommended** to do in this way.

Comment: As you've already noted yourself, this isn't a good practice. Since it is a method and not a function he would have to make sure that it is callable as a function. A rabbit hole he certainly doesn't want to conquer.